# block execute php script if another one execute it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $pw = "root";
 $db_name = "marketing";

 $Connect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pw) or die("Couldn't connect to+ MySQL:<0br>" . mysqli_error($Connect) . "<br>" . mysqli_errno($Connect));

 $Db = mysqli_select_db($Connect, $db_name)or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysqli_error($Connect). "<br>" . mysqli_errno($Connect));

 mysqli_set_charset($Connect, "utf8");

 mysqli_autocommit($Connect,TRUE);  

 $query1 = "select status from cron_statuses where offset = 0";
 $res = mysqli_query($Connect, $query1); 
 $status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

 if (!$status['status']){

    $query2 = "update cron_statuses set status = 1 where offset = 0";
    $res = mysqli_query($Connect, $query2);

    //do something
    sleep(20);

     $query2 = "update cron_statuses set status = 0 where offset = 0";
     $res = mysqli_query($Connect, $query2);
}
else{
    echo 'cron blocked';
 }     

?>
```

Default value for status = 0. if I run the script it will then update status to 1 and then sleep 20 secs and update the status back to 0.

Whiles sleeping, if the script is run in another tab I would expect the status to equal to 1, and should enter the echo `cron_block` but if its = 0 it should do the same as the first tab.

Comment: during the sleep , status will be 1 anyways right ?? whats is the isssue than ?

Comment: What is the storage type you use? With Transaction support? What's the autocommit setting? If you're using transaction storage and not setting autocommit to true, your UPDATE is hole up until you commit and other connections may capable to read the old value.

Comment: I would expect your status would be different for different tabs, you should be able to test for session id's if they are still the same

Comment: status is int(1): 0 or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue because I run the same script in same browser (firefox) with 2 tabs.

when I run the first on firefox and the second in chrome the behaviors went as I expected.

also, when run the first with localhost/script.php and the other 192.10.1.5/script.php on same browser with different tabs the behaviors went as I expected.

I do not know why but the issue not in code.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your case IF I create a table using ENGINE=InnoDB and set autocommit to FALSE. This is my testing code, more or less the same as yours except setting autocommit to FALSE forcefully:

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password");
$db = mysqli_select_db($dbconn,"test");

mysqli_autocommit($dbconn,FALSE);

$res = mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT status FROM test WHERE offset = 0;");
$status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if ( $status['status'] == 0 ) {
    $res = mysqli_query($dbconn,"UPDATE test SET status = 1 WHERE offset = 0;");
    sleep(10);
    $res = mysqli_query($dbconn,"UPDATE test SET status = 0 WHERE offset = 0;");
}
```

So please double check your table is using storage engine that support transaction or not, and what's the default autocommit setting.

Best Regards,

Ken

Comment: cron_statuses ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: If so, add mysqli_autocommit($Connect, TRUE); after mysqli_set_charset($Connect, "utf8"); and try again!

Comment: I added "mysqli_autocommit($Connect, TRUE); after "mysqli_set_charset($Connect, "utf8"); the same issue.

Comment: if I put exit in top of page after the one is started the second is stuck. the issue seems is the script is stuck or something like this.